# how to get all the selected values of all radio buttons on submit in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get data from the database and after selecting the radio buttons want to sent data to another PHP file. For one radio button selection, it is ok. But how to store all the radio button selection?

```
<form  action = "process.php" method = "post">

    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $question = $row['QUESTION'];
        $option1 = $row['OPTION_1'];
        $option2 = $row['OPTION_2'];
        $option3 = $row['OPTION_3'];
        $option4 = $row['OPTION_4'];
        ?>

        <?php echo $question ?> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer"<?php echo $i ?>"value="A"><?php echo $option1 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $i ?>" value="B"><?php echo $option2 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $i ?>" value="C"><?php echo $option3 ?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $i ?>" value="D"><?php echo $option3 ?><br>
        <?php echo "" ?><br>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Use the array syntax maybe: ```name="answer[]"```. You can customize this to your liking, with numeric/associative indexes and nested arrays.

Comment: you may want to use checkbox for this. `type="checkbox"`

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is as the above looks like it should work OK and yield an answer ( of the form `answer1`, `answer2`,.... `answerX` ) in the POST array. If that is so what is the question?